# Redirect to subdomain if user request subdomain WP

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, .htaccess, ssl

I install WP in main domain example.com and there is the .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

How I can redirect the user who requests {subdomain}.example.com to app.example.com/{subdomain} but if they just want example.com to give them index.php file like it is now?

Also how to keep {subdomain}.example.com in the browser instead of showing app.example.com/{subdomain} ?

**UPDATE:**
my wildcard subdomains are already redirected to the main domain ...

Comment: my wildcard subdomains are already redirected to the main domain ...

Comment: THIS IS NO DUPLICATE BECAUSE I ALREADY REDIRECT ALL SUBDOMAINS TO MAIN DOMAIN

Comment: "Also how to keep {subdomain}.example.com in the browser instead of showing app.example.com/{subdomain} ?"About this part - do you want that user see {subdomain}.example.com, if they are looking at app.example.com/{subdomain} ?

Comment: Yes thats what i want

Answer (score 0):

Even you can do it with PHP or JS

### Add this lines at the top of your  `public_html/subdomain/index.php`

```
<?php
  if($_SERVER[HTTP_HOST] == "example.com"){
    header("location:http://sub.example.com");
    exit();
 }
```

Since you are using WordPress , it would be better to use this code snippet at the top of your `wp-blog-header.php` And now you are all set.

Comment: no, this is not the answer...